# Simple PHP Form Not Working - 500 Internal Server Error - Parallels Plesk Panel 9.5

Tags: php, contact-form, plesk

I'm stumped why this contact form returns a 500 Internal Server Error. I am 99% sure that my code is immaculate.

I am using Parallels Plesk Panel 9.5 as my hosting admin control panel. I have found Log Manager, and checked in both Access Logs and Error Logs. In Error Logs there are entries for [error] [client 162.247.90.74], [error] [client 184.164.146.26] which say file doesn't exist, and [error] [client 216.21.233.2] which says cannot create or spawn child process.

My HTML form on contact.html:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="mailer.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2"><small>Name</small></label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
           </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2"><small>Email</small></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email, example@domain.com" required>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2"><small>Telephone</small></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="Enter your telephone number" required>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2"><small>Message</small></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="inputMessage" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Enter your message here" required></textarea>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="antispam">Leave this empty:
        <br /><input name="url" /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input style="font-size:22px;" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The mailer.php document:

```
 <?php

 // if the url field is empty
 if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){

// then send the form to your email
mail( 'info@website.com', 'Contact Form', print_r($_POST,true) );
}

// otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through

// redirect to thank you page

header('Location: http://www.website.com/thankyou.html');
exit('Redirecting you to http://www.website.com/thankyou.html');

?>
```

Comment: I am *99%* sure that your host is not immaculate and configured wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to tell from the information that I provided what I need to do to my host to fix this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that is an issue you will need to contact your hosting support provider about

Comment: Why your `<label for="` tags are different from your inputs ids?

Comment: @mituw16 I have called my hosting support provider and they said they can't help me with custom code (they're referring to my mailer.php document). I told them this is their problem. They said it's not. Are they b.s.ing me?

Comment: @ThiagoAugustusOliveira I used ="name" for both Name and Telephone because I figured it was easier. No real reason.

Answer (score 1):

I called my hosting provider and harassed them some more. They said that the account was "holding memory" so they refreshed it and now it works. Well, I guess that's the answer!

Comment: Great! That is a common occurrence with shared hosting providers (having to harras them to get them to actually help you)